# How to implement paging of array inside another array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, emulation, paging

I'm writing an emulator for the [mc9s12dp256](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC9S12DP256.pdf) which has the flash EEPROM memory (256KiB in size), which is divided into small pages 16KiB in size and loaded into the normal memory at offset 0x83FC from the start of the memory.

I emulate the normal memory as an array of uint8_t of size 65536 and the flash EEPROM memory as an array of uint8_t and size 262144.

My question is: How can I implement this paging, preferably without copying the entire page between the EEPROM memory array and the normal memory array, and if there is any way to "mount" it on there?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement this paging"? You have only mentioned sizes and arrays. That is not what I would describe as paging.

Comment: I have 2 arrays and I need to "mount" a page (16KiB) of an array inside another one basically.

Comment: The simplest will be to do the memcpy. It may seem like a waste for a powerful pentium processor, but I'm sure it will be fast enough.

Comment: There are mechanisms to implement virtualisation maps in both unix and windows, but you may find that you can't get the granularity. Generally these mechanisms have been designed around paging in portions of files, but they can be equally used to map in-memory objects.

Comment: Please show how your code would look like if the "mounting" were implemented successfully. I.e. how would code use the feature. Maybe it can then be deduced what you mean by mounting.

Comment: By "mounting" I mean something like the linux command mount, but for an array and inside another one. But anyways, I saved the Flash EEPROM to a file and then used mmap to map it to implement this "mounting" or paging or however you wanna call this